# RIght Justify the array of strings in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, justify

I have a method Justify that should right justify the array of strings based on

the longest string in the array.I have written the below method Justify that

determines the length of the longest string and then tries to right justify all

the elements of string array with respect to longest string.

```
public static void justify(String[] text) {

    int maxlength=text[0].length();
    int currentlength;
    for(int i=1;i<text.length;i++){
        currentlength=text[i].length();
        if(maxlength<currentlength){
            maxlength=currentlength;
        }
    }

    for(int j=0;j<text.length;j++){
        if(text[j].length()<maxlength){
            text[j]=new String(String.format("%1$-" + maxlength + "s", text[j]));

        }
    }

    for(String s:text){
        System.out.print(s+"\n");
    }
}
```

My string array is {"AMIT","JOHNNY","ROHAN"}.

Please help me on this.

Comment: why add parenthesis after `.length`

Comment: @Mark because it's the string length method. Array length is `text.length`, string length is `text[i].length()`.

Comment: I thought this was C#

Comment: It's always not a pleasure to see the `String(String)` constructor being used when it's unnecessary...

Comment: @ fabian  Yeah that unnecessary...thanks for pointing out that.

Answer (score 1):

You can change you for loop like this

```
StringBuilder sb;
for(int j=0;j<text.length;j++){
    sb=new StringBuiler();
    //append appropriate spaces
    for(int i=0,len=text[j].length();i<maxlength-len;i++){
       sb.append(" ");
    }
    text[j]=sb.toString()+text[j];
}
```